# How to Filter out Duplicate rows(By a specific column) in Excel or Open Office CALC ??

Tags: excel, excel-2010, openoffice-calc

I want to filter out rows in Excel/Open Office CALC like this :

```
    Here is My Table Structure 

   Emp_No and Note Added are the column names 



  Emp_no.                Note added

    10             salary due by 13th Oct

    10                salary pending

    10                  salary paid

    10                salary not paid

    23                   salary paid  

    23         salary not paid for 2 months

    23             salary due this month
```

Now, I want to keep only the first **ROW** from the set of rows containing **Emp_No** as **10** and keep only first **ROW** from the next set of values containing **Emp_No** value as **23**.

So in short, I want a output like this :

```
   Emp_no.               Note added

    10             salary due by 13th Oct
    23                   salary paid
```

Kindly help !!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

With a helper column this formula:

```
=IF(B1=B2,"",B2)
```

in Row2 and copied down should pick out the first instance (each change) in `Emp_no.`, if that is in ColumnB.

Filtering to select (Blanks) in the column with these formulae should then pick out all the rows where the `Emp_no.` is the same as the row immediately above - at which point they may be deleted to achieve the result shown as required from the data sample provided.